# Question regarding limiting probability

Tags: markov-process

Does there exist an irreducible discrete time Markov chain such that all limiting probabilities exist, i.e. $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_k = i)$ exists for all states $i$, and $\sum_{i} \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_k = i) = \frac{1}{2}$? I'm currently stuck here and not sure how to prove/disprove this. Is there any suggestion on how I should proceed?

Comment: If I understand your notation and terminology, it seems to me the sum of limits has to b $1.$ Terminology can differ among texts. If you allow periodic chains maybe 1/2 is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $2\times 2$ transition matrix, shown below.  In R,
matrix multiplication is denoted `%*%` We show the transition
matrix of an irreducible ergodic chain, and how to obtain its
limiting distribution.

**First approach:** Take higher powers of transition matrix, until
all rows of $\mathbf{P}^n$ become (nearly) the same.

```
P = matrix(c(.4, .6,
             .7, .3), byrow=T, nrow=2)
P.2 = P %*% P;  P.4 = P.2 %*% P.2;  P.4
       [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 0.5422 0.4578
[2,] 0.5341 0.4659
P.8 = P.4 %*% P.4;  P.16 = P.8 %*% P.8;  P.16
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5384615 0.4615385
[2,] 0.5384615 0.4615385
```

So the 16th power of the transition matrix shows that the
steady state, thus limiting, distribution is the vector
$\sigma = (0.5384615,\, 0.4615385).$

**Another approach,** using eigenvectors: The left eigenvector
with the smallest modulus, listed first in R output, is proportional to $\sigma.$
Because R finds right eigenvectors, we use the transpose of
the transition matrix $\mathbf{P}.$

```
g = eigen(t(P))$vector[,1]; g  # first column of matris of eigenvectors
[1] 0.7592566 0.6507914
sg = g/sum(g);  sg
[1] 0.5384615 0.4615385

sg %*% P                       # verification
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5384615 0.4615385
```

**Third approach** is possible tor a 2-state irreducible ergodic Markov Chain.
Starting in state 1, the mean waiting time to transition to state 2 is (by geometric
distribution $1/.6.$ Then the mean waiting time to return to state 1 is
$1/.7.$ Thus on average, over the long run, the chain spends $\frac{1/.6}{1/.6 + 1/.7} = \frac{7}{13} = 0.5384615$ of its time in state 1.

```
1/6/(1/6 + 1/7)
[1] 0.5384615
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand the reasoning above. The sum of the limiting probabilities in all the examples is still 1. So I guess the question above is not true? Do you have any suggestion how to disprove it?

Comment: Not sure I understand question. My answer is is correct and contains info you might find useful, but maybe irrelevant to current question.